# Comparing string to other strings sequencially

Tags: java

I want to be able to compare one string to all other strings sequentially and then move down to the next string and compare that strings to all the other strings below it.

Here is the code I have.  It compares the first string correctly and finds no matches.  However when the other for loop moves to the next value of i, everystring =1 and so does i so it compares itself.  How can I go about moving the inner for loop one value each time I go through the other loop?

```
for (int everystring = 0; everystring < children.length; everystring++) {

   String current = children[everystring].substring(0,
         children[everystring].indexOf("_"));

   for (int i = 1; i < children.length; i++) {
      String innercurrent = children[i].substring(0,
            children[i].indexOf("_"));

      if (current.equalsIgnoreCase(innercurrent)) {

         System.out.println("Match");
      } else
         System.out.println("No Match");
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: that would compare the string to itself.

Comment: I fixed it by adding i = everystring+1 in the outer for loop.

Comment: Can you include some sample data?  That might help if we knew your intent.  In any case, you can always increment a loop counter while you're inside a loop.  just say i++; or everystring++;

Comment: @user541597: Please don't change the question body if it completely changes the issue at hand. Future readers might learn from this as well - and if you edit it, they will have no idea what this thread is about. I rolled back to previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loop always from 0 to `children.length` [in inner loop], **and add the following condition** in the beginning of the inner loop:

```
if (i == everything) continue;
```

It will skip every iteration of the inner loop where `i == everything`, so you will only check for strings that are unequal.

Note however that **you will check each 2 strings twice** (for example: you will check `i == 1`, `everything == 2` and  `i == 2, everything == 1`

If you don't want it: **iterate in inner loop from `everything + 1` until `children.length`**

Comment: OP asked to "...compare that strings to all the other strings below it...".  Your answer would just avoid matching the string to itself, as opposed to skipping all previously checked strings.

Comment: @sharakan: "Below it" is not a clear definition, I gave both possibilities and included explanation for both, he can chose what he prefers.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, all you need to do is use the value of `everystring` in the initializer of your inner loop:

```
for (int everystring = 0; everystring < children.length; everystring++) {
    String current = children[everystring].substring(0,
     children[everystring].indexOf("_"));
    for (int i = everystring+1; i < children.length; i++) {
        String innercurrent = children[i].substring(0,
        children[i].indexOf("_"));

        if (current.equalsIgnoreCase(innercurrent)) {

            System.out.println("Match");
        } else
           System.out.println("No Match");
        }
    System.out.println();
 }
```

This will compare each string to all strings that appear after it in the array.

Comment: This will cause an arrayindexoutofbounds when everystring == children.length - 1.

Comment: @RalfHoppen it won't. `i < children.length == false` when `i == children.length`

Answer (score 0):

```
This.
for (int everystring = 0; everystring < children.length - 1; everystring++) {

   String current = children[everystring].substring(0,
         children[everystring].indexOf("_"));

   for (int i = everystring + 1; i < children.length; i++) {
      String innercurrent = children[i].substring(0,
            children[i].indexOf("_"));

      if (current.equalsIgnoreCase(innercurrent)) {

         System.out.println("Match");
      } else
         System.out.println("No Match");
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int i = 0;      

   for (int everystring = 0; everystring<children.length; everystring++){

       String current = children[everystring].substring(0,children[everystring].indexOf("_"));

       i = everystring+1;

   for (;i<children.length; i++){
       String innercurrent = children[i].substring(0,children[i].indexOf("_"));



      if(current.equalsIgnoreCase(innercurrent)){

      System.out.println("Match");
      }else System.out.println("No Match");

      /* if (current.substring(0,current.indexOf("_")).equalsIgnoreCase(innercurrent.substring(0,innercurrent.indexOf("_")))){




           System.out.println("Match");


       }*/

   }
   System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange code you got there .__. but I would do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < children.length - 1; i++) {
   String current = children[i].substring(0,children[i].indexOf("_"));

   for (int j = i + 1; j < children.length; j++) {
       String compareTo = children[j].substring(0,children[j].indexOf("_"));

       if (current.equalsIgnoreCase(compareTo))
           System.out.format("%s matches %s\n", current, compareTo);
       else
           System.out.format("%s doesn't matches %s\n", current, compareTo);
   }
}
```

this way you compare everything only once and you don't compare the same position to itself.